# Is there a way to put multiple columns in pyspark array function? (FP Growt prep)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, fpgrowth

I have a DataFrame with symptoms of a disease, I want to run FP Growt on the entire DataFrame. FP Growt wants an array as input and it works with this code:

```
dfFPG = (df.select(F.array(df["Gender"], 
                        df["Polyuria"], 
                        df["Polydipsia"], 
                        df["Sudden weight loss"], 
                        df["Weakness"], 
                        df["Polyphagia"],
                        df["Genital rush"],
                        df["Visual blurring"],
                        df["Itching"]).alias("features")

from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="features", minSupport=0.3, minConfidence=0.2)
model = fpGrowth.fit(dfFPG)

model.freqItemsets.show(20,truncate=False)
```

the features list is longer and if I have to change the name of df I have to use find and replace. I know I can use `F.col("Gender")` instead of `df["Gender"]` but is there a way to put all the columns inside `F.array()` in once and be able to exclude few of them like `df["Age"]`?
Or, is there any other efficient way to prepare categorical features to FP Growt that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the column names using `df.columns` and put them all into the `array`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

dfFPG = df.select(F.array(*[c for c in df.columns if c not in ['col1', 'col2']]).alias("features"))
```

Comment: thanks, it is useful for sure but I just updated the question because I realized later that I have also to exclude few columns. Is there a way to use `df.columns` minus some columns?

Comment: @Nic see edited answer. you can specify unwanted columns col1, col2, etc

Comment: in the meantime I solved in 2 step in a more naive way with `a=df.columns;
a.remove("Age")` and then use `*a`

Comment: @Nic that's also a nice way! more readable than mine

Comment: but anyway, is this the best way to prepare a DataFrame for FP Growt or there is some specific transformer?

Comment: @Nic I think it looks alright. I'm not familiar with FPGrowth, but for other Spark ML algos, normally vectorassembler is used